# Which Datastructure can i use for the boardgame Nine men's morris?

Tags: java

Im trying to programm the game Nine men's morris (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nine_men%27s_morris).
But i dont know which datastructure of the Collection Library would fit best for saving the pieces and their positions on the board.
My first Idea for the datastructure was:
Board = array
pieces = arrayList
But then it was hard to check if there are 3 in a row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go with three lists:

One for each "ring":
Let's imagine you start each list in the bottom left corner and continue clockwise.

```
-> List#1 contains A1, A4, A7, D7, G7, G4, G1, D1 // outer ring
-> List#2 contains B2, B4, B6, D6, F6, F4, F2, D2 // middle ring
-> List#3 contains C3, C4, C5, D5, E5, E4, E3, D3 // inner ring
```

To check if there are three in a row in a ring:
For each list, check listitems

```
0 == 1 == 2 (lower left to upper left) or 
2 == 3 == 4 (upper left to upper right) or
4 == 5 == 6 (upper right to lower right) or 
6 == 7 == 0 (lower right to lower left)
```

For the "connections" between the rings you have to check, if the odd entries of each list match, e.g.

```
list1[1] == list2[1] == list3[1]
list1[3] == list2[3] == list3[3]
...
list1[7] == list2[7] == list3[7]
```

This should be pretty easily implemented in java

Comment: I think this is the pragmatic, reasonable implementation. Another more "pure" version would be a graph of nodes with labels on the connections to indicate the direction of the connection. Far easier to extend to other board shapes, but much trickier to implement and understand in the concrete case.